# connecting to a public database through vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

i am wondering if there is a public database where you can test your SQL and can connect to? i would like to test a connection to a database using vb.net, and would like to run a few sql statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not one I am aware of. As Max said you can install Express edition and try it out locally. If you still want to test with a public DB then drop mean email at shobankr[at]gmail.com .. I have a public DB which I use to test my apps.

Answer (score 2):

Someone may have something like this, but why would you want to use a public database? Normally you would just install something like [Microsoft SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx) and test locally. That way you control the environment.

Answer (score 1):

If the specific flavor of SQL isn't important, try [FreeSQL](http://www.freesql.org/).  It's good for doing some light SQL testing, running SQL statements, and just generally good for learning SQL.  They offer MySQL and PostGreSQL databases.

If you want SQL Server, ideally you would install SQL Express as Max mentions.